# Can Microsoft Graph access Azure resources?

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using oauth2 to connect to Microsoft Graph, and I have access 
 to the user profile (using https://graph.windows.net/TENANT_ID/me).

Is there a way to access a user's Azure resources? specifically Storage Blobs?

Comment: Just by using Graph API it is not possible. You would need to use Azure Resource Manager API or Azure Subscription Management API to manage Azure resources. Could you describe your scenario in more details?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by user's storage blobs? Storage blobs are not directly associated with users as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Graph (https://graph.microsoft.com) exposes user and group centric data. For Azure resources use the ARM API.